# Laravel get column as array list

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I iterate a certain column when make a query using Eloquent laravel orm.

```
public function getProductAPI(Request $request)
    {

        $id = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->id;

        $product = Product::where('user_id',$id)->get()->toArray();

        foreach ($product->description as $desc) { 

            dd($desc);
        }
        dd($product);


        return response()->json($product);
    }
```

Both `$product->description` and `$product["description"]` returning an error of `Undefined index: description` and `Trying to get property of non-object`

### EDIT:

This are the output of dd($product):

```
 array:2 [
      0 => array:15 [
        "id" => 1
        "user_id" => 24
        "title" => "Langkawi"
        "description" => "Lorem ipsum WTF???"
        "category" => 1
        "city" => 2
        "image_url" => "https://qwert.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/no-image.png"
        "price" => "30"
        "location" => "Langkawi"
        "discount" => "10%"
        "start_date" => "0000-00-00"
        "end_date" => "0000-00-00"

      ]
      1 => array:15 [
        "id" => 6
        "user_id" => 24
        "title" => "ADVANCE AND DEFENSIVE DRIVING COURSE # SHAH ALAM"
        "description" => "Lorem ipsum WTF??? V2"
        "category" => 0
        "city" => 0
        "image_url" => "https://qwert.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/no-image.png"
        "price" => ""
        "location" => ""
        "discount" => ""
        "start_date" => "0000-00-00"
        "end_date" => "0000-00-00"

      ]
    ]
```

I cant specifically get a column for modification.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you `dd($product);`?

Comment: @aldrin27 dd($product) would return all the items from db, yes can.

Comment: @aldrin27 checkout the edit

Comment: Check what is @rome answered.

Comment: If you want that to be an object. Or is it going to be an array?

Comment: I want it to be object

Comment: Then look at the answer.

Comment: It convert to array by default!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need use toArray();

Check it:

```
public function getProductAPI(Request $request)
{

    $id = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->id;

    $product = Product::where('user_id',$id)->get();

    foreach ($product as $desc) { 

        echo dd($desc->description);
    }
    echo dd($product);


    return response()->json($product);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can iterate through all the value rather than using dd() and stopped at one result.

Comment: Inside the foreach. `$newDesc[] = $desc->description` then outside your foreach `print_r($newDesc)`

Comment: How can I assign back to $product it self? Lets say I replace all description as null

Comment: Try it: $leng = count($product);  for($i=0;$i<$leng;$i++) {$product[$i]['description']= '';}

Answer (score 0):

Your $product variable is an array. Try with $product[0]['description'].
Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

on function getProductAPI:
{

```
$uniq_id = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->id;

$product = Product::where('user_id',$uniq_id)->get()->toArray();

foreach ($product as $desc) { 

    dd($desc->description);
}
echo dd($product);


return response()->json($product);
```

}